What could cause Bambu Studio and Cura to skip a layer when building G-code?
I have checked the model of the "Air Fresh Top" more than once and it is manifold. You can see in the photo from the link above that it prints with the entire section missing.
The slicers skip adding a layer in the area indicated in the image below. How do I get it to add a layer?


Probably an incorrect model, that is, if 2 different slicers do the same! How is the model created, and can the model be shared or found on Thingiverse or Printables? Please share in order for the community to help you.

Here is link - https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6778446. You can see in the photo that it prints with the entire section missing.

Thanks, but next time please incorporate requested information in your answer to get a complete question. Note that comments may be deleted, comments are basically for others to request for information after which the OP incorporates this by [edit] in the question.

So, if the original designer of the model cannot print it correctly as well, it surely must be an error in the model. Many models designed in Blender have issues. Unfortunately I cannot check the model as I have no computer access at the moment, hence a comment, not an answer.

There is nothing wrong with the slicers; it's the model that has a minor design error.
When the model is cut in half it's easier to see the mistake.


The slicer tries to fix that issue with an overhang wall (blue), but evidently it's not very stable.

I printed this "Air Fresh Top" (with a 0.6 mm nozzle)...
(Please don't mind that single loop of spaghetti.)

... but the ridge came off very easily. I'm not exactly sure what the purpose of that ridge even is.


I see now. Thank you. The ledge is for fitting the top on the container snugly.

@S.James Then you'll have to fix the model. Good luck!
